# Delay iteration of an collection in RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

**My actual requirement:**

I have a list of custom objects, and I want to iterate it with a delay. I can't use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` in my `for` loop since my iterations create a `CoreData` object that triggers `FetchedResultController` and hence updates my `TableView`. Anyway, so I tried using Rx to iterate my list with a delay of 1 second each. But I am unable to do so.

**Question**

I want to delay the iteration of each element of the array using RxSwift.
I was able to do it in Java, but couldn't do so in RxSwift.

the `.delay()` operator didn't help either, it just delayed the whole process.

Any example would help, thus I am not posting any specific code... but this is what I've been trying so far

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Observable.from(array)
  .delay(RxTimeInterval(5), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
  .subscribe { (intValue) in
    print("onNext() \(intValue)")
}
```

Output

```
onNext() next(1)
onNext() next(2)
onNext() next(3)
onNext() next(4)
onNext() next(5)
onNext() completed
```

The output gets printed after 5 seconds, not with 5 seconds interval.

I am not getting any integer values, but a `next(1)`.

Comment: Why not use a simple timer? `Observable<Int>.interval(5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)`

Comment: @SandeepBhandari Ummm, because Static member 'interval' cannot be used on an instance of type 'Observable<Observable<_>.E>' ? 

Comment: Am not sure of your requirement, are you trying to simply iterate through array (of primitive type like Int or you are trying to combine an array of observables) if its just an array of int you can use timer as I mentioned else you can use combine latest or zip and then apply throttle probably

Comment: I have a list of custom objects, and I want to iterate it with a delay. I can't use `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` in my `for` loop since my iterations create a CoreData object that triggers FetchedResultController and hence updates my tableView. Anyway, so I tried using Rx to iterate my list with a delay of 1 second each. But I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common confusion. As you have learned `delay` will be applied to every element equally so all of them are delayed by five seconds, rather than putting a five second delay between each event. (So the first event happens immediately, the second at five seconds, the third at ten, and so on.

Once you realize that what you are really trying to do is put a delay *between* each event, the solution becomes more clear. Or at least, the reason why just putting a delay on the `from` operator isn't working should be more clear.

The solution is to use one of the flatMap variants:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Observable.from(array)
    .concatMap { Observable.empty().delay(.seconds(5), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).startWith($0) }
    .subscribe { (intValue) in
        print("onNext() \(intValue)")
    }
```

The line `Observable.empty().delay(.seconds(5), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).startWith($0)` will immediately emit the value, but then wait five seconds before emitting a completed event.

The `concatMap` operator calls the closure on each incoming event and concats the resulting Observables together so that following Observables aren't subscribed to, until the previous one completes.

Learn more about this in my article, [*The Many Faces of FlatMap*](https://danielt1263.medium.com/rxswifts-many-faces-of-flatmap-5764e6c2018c)

---

An alternative solution based on the comments that Sandeep Bhandari wrote on the question would be to use an interval to constrain when the `from` operator can emit values. Something like this:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Observable.zip(Observable.from(array), Observable<Int>.interval(.seconds(5), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).take(while: { $0 != array.count }))
    .map { $0 }
    .subscribe { (intValue) in
        print("onNext() \(intValue)")
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for that! After a lot of scrolling through docs, I came up with the same solution. Thought I was doing it the "bad" way so didn't delete my post.